# Why am I unsuccessful in passing an argument to a function in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have the following very simple program that takes a list of integers and a single integer. It then checks the entire list using map to see how many member of the list are the same as the passed integer. then it returns the number of those elements by finding the length of the list that map generated. However, I am not able to pass my first integer-argument in my first function (Integer-Bool). Why is that and how can I fix it? Thanks

```
import Data.List (genericLength)

count::(Integer->Bool)->[Integer]->Integer
count op xs = genericLength (filter(True ==) (map op xs))

main = do
print $ count 3 [3, 4, 5, 3, 5, 3]
```

This code should run as follows:

> -first, it applies map  to the list and returns a new list: [True, False, False, True, False, True]
>
> -second, it applies filter to filter out all the True's and we get a new list: [True, True, True]
>
> -third, it applies genericLength to figure out the length of this last list, thus returning: 3

Comment: In what way is `3` an operation on numbers?

Comment: It's not. But what should I have. Perhaps (==3)?

Comment: `filter(True ==) (map op xs)` is an awfully strange way to spell `filter op xs`.

Comment: @DanielWagner I know it is, but the requirement of the question was that it uses both map and filter. I know we could just filter out the specified integer from the list and then count the occurences of those filtered elements. But that would not even need a function-argument, which is what the purpose of that silly question was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it. it needs to be called like this:

```
print $ count (==3) [3, 4, 5, 3, 5, 3]
```